# Oracle sql decode

Tags: sql, oracle, count, decode

I'm trying to decode this to simple read midwest instead of the number counted.

```
DECODE(COUNT(location_id),true,'Midwest')
```

I have a feeling I'm overlooking something simple.

Comment: Unclear what you want to achieve? When do you want to show "Midwest" instead of the count?

Comment: In the exact Spot the count of the rows are. Instead of a count I want it to say "Midwest"

Comment: Decode is used instead of if..else...eg: Decode(value, 0, 'Zero')..here when do you need to display 'midwest'??

Comment: `count(location_id)` returns a number.  `true` is a boolean so it doesn't make sense to compare them.  If you always want to replace the count with a string, why not just select a constant string in the first place?

Comment: I guess you need to display midwest when count is not zero...DECODE(COUNT(location_id),0,'Zero','Midwest').

Comment: Thanks alot Justin and Sachu. I didn't think about comparing it to a string vs a boolean. I appreaciate your time though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CASE WHEN (COUNT(location_id) > 0) THEN 'Midwest'
     ELSE -- Optional
       'Some thing else' -- Optional
END
```

You can use a Case, to check if the count() is > 0

Comment: I like this one. Thanks Maheswaran!

Comment: @JacobKocina Welcome, Also accept it as answer if it helped ;)